# NodeJS Jest : Testing function that imports module using require.main.require

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to write unit testing using Jest for a Node JS project. It was importing all the modules using require.main.require

Below are the simulation of the issue. Code can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-jest-demo?file=index.js

I have the following test file present in ***my root directory*** in which I am importing index.js

**./sample.pass.test.js**

```
const { checkUser } = require('./index');

console.log(checkUser); // This is purely to check If i can access checkUser from this file or not

describe('Testing...', () => {
  it('Should pass', () => {
    expect(0).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

In my index.js I am importing another function using require.main.require

```
const { getUserById } = require.main.require('./models/UserModel');

function checkUser(id) {
  const user = getUserById(id);
  return user ? 'Found' : 'Not Found';
}

module.exports.checkUser = checkUser;
```

The above test case is passing. But If I were to place the same test file in some other directly (like _*test_* ) then it fails.

E.g.: **./__*test*__/sample.fail.test.js**

> Notice here I adjusted require statement of index since it is now one level up

```
const { checkUser } = require('../index');

console.log(checkUser);

describe('Testing...', () => {
  it('Should pass', () => {
    expect(0).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

The result shows it is unable to access UserModel.

```
Cannot find module './models/UserModel' from '__tests__/sample.fail.test.js'

    Require stack:
      index.js
      __tests__/sample.fail.test.js

    > 1 | const { getUserById } = require.main.require('./models/UserModel');
        |                                      ^
      2 |
      3 | function checkUser(id) {
      4 |   const user = getUserById(id);
```

What could be the solution in this case?

Thank in advance!